# How can I let people post a form submission publicly in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5

Not sure why I can't get this to work... To clarify, I have a `form` that I want the general public to be able to submit to. Then, the index page is for logged in admin only...

**Edit: I'm using `devise` for authentication.

I've done the following:

1. Put the `before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new]` in
   my controller
2. Setup a `/new` route in my `routes.rb`
3. Moved the `def xyz_params` outside of the `private` area...

What else am I missing?

Comment: This depends entirely on your application. A default scaffolded rails application will let anybody create and modify resources.

Comment: I'll add an edit that I'm using devise for authentication... Thought that was obvious because of the "before_action :authenticate_user!" but I understand how that's not a given.

Comment: Still not good enough. Provide examples of the actual code in question. This is not a discussion form - its a QA site for questions that can be answered. You're just leaving us with a bunch of guesswork about what the makeup of your app is.

Comment: The `private` keyword also has nothing to do with authorization or authentication. Rather it means that the method can only be called from within the class - so you can't do `foo.new.bar` if `bar` is private.

Comment: Ah okay - Will post more of the code here shortly... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with others that you should have given more code, I think this is enough to figure it out.

It should be as simple as adding the ":create" to the:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new, :create]
```

Let me know if this works...